# INNER JOIN empty set

Tags: mysql

[image]

Here is the specific task:
****Write an SQL query that will display the following fields: (region id, region name, warehouse state, and warehouse country) of all the regions with and without warehouses****

What is wrong with my query that is making me return an empty set?

Comment: We can't see your query. Can you put it on your post?

Comment: SELECT s_warehouse.region_id, s_region.name, s_warehouse.state, s_warehouse.country
FROM s_warehouse INNER JOIN s_region
ON s_warehouse.id = s_region.id;

Comment: I think you can figure it out by using `s_warehouse.region_id = s_region.id`

Comment: No image was necessary for this question. All of your SQL is able to be copied and pasted here, as text, into the question itself. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate the issue. Here's a [Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) that explains the reasons images should be avoided. Please [edit] your question to remove the image and include the text instead, and properly format it so that it's readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `warehouse.id` is probably not the same as your `region.id`. Rather, the join on the table should be between your `warehouse.region_id` and your `region.id` as those are the fields that the two tables share (I assume).

Try:

```
SELECT s_warehouse.region_id, s_region.name, s_warehouse.state, s_warehouse.country 
FROM s_warehouse 
    INNER JOIN s_region ON s_warehouse.region_id = s_region.id;
```